# Django DateTimeField showing up as string

Tags: django, python-3.x

Hi one of my Django models has a the following field

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
```

However when I check the data type it shows as String

```
 print(self.created_at)
 print(type(self.created_at))

2018-01-10T20:53:19Z
<class 'str'>
```

Funny thing is the same code running on my production server shows it as

```
2016-04-21 09:38:38+00:00
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

I am using python3 and Django 1.10.6.

Any idea what is causing this ?

Comment: Can you show where you are printing the values?

Comment: Its within the save() method of the model

Comment: Please post the entire method.

Comment: def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print(self.created_at)
            print(type(self.created_at))
            super(ZDTickets, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: seeing the same thing here with django 3.2

Answer (score 3):

Databases don't store Python data types, so the django ORM does some transforming and casting for you to return you an equivalent Python type.

> For example, DateField fields use a Python datetime object to store
>   data. Databases don’t store datetime objects, so the field value must
>   be converted into an ISO-compliant date string for insertion into the
>   database.

(From the [documentation on the `save()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#what-happens-when-you-save))

This only works if there is already data to be read from that particular field.

In other words, if you are creating a new record, the value will be a string because there is no existing value to the field.

If the object is being updated, then the value will be an date time object if you haven't updated that field.

Django uses the same `save()` method for creating new records and updating existing records.

Comment: The value that I try to store to this field is of type str eg: 2018-01-10T20:53:19Z. In my production server it saves it as a Datetime object but on my development server its storing as str

Comment: seeing the same thing here with 3.2