# save() method in Django model receiving string instead of date object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Currently we're migrating Django from version 1.11.29 to version 3.2.15 and one thing that we noticed is that the `DateFields` in the `save()` method in models is now a string instead of a `Date` object as it used to be.

this is one of the fields that now is a string

```
service_date_starts = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True,)
```

is this expected? or is there a way the `DateFields` in `save()` still be an object without parsing?

Answer (score 1):

This could help you.

[Django DateTimeField showing up as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51296799/django-datetimefield-showing-up-as-string)

I let you some information from that question.

> Databases don't store Python data types, so the django ORM does some transforming and casting for you to return you an equivalent Python type.
>
> In other words, if you are creating a new record, the value will be a
> string because there is no existing value to the field.
>
> If the object is being updated, then the value will be an date time
> object if you haven't updated that field.

Comment: the weird thing is that this broke a test that passed in the older django version, do you know if something in `save()` changed between those versions?